# Setting up ACL on a VPS?

Tags: 10.04, server, vps

I am relatively new at using Linux and have just installed a fresh(ish) copy of Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS Minimal install running on a HyperVM VPS.

How would I enable ACL? I have a question on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/233438/user-permissions-on-ubuntu-linux/) which resolved the problem I was trying to solve on a virtual machine running Ubuntu Server 10.10.

`df -T` yields `/dev/simfs` of type `reiserfs` - What would I put in fstab to mount ACL for the file system? At the moment this file is blank.

after running `sudo mount -o remount,acl /` I get `mount:permission denied`. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Marked as solved as from all the research that I have done it's been concluded that I am unable to use ACL's on a VPS due to permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Reiserfs simply doesn't have support for access control lists. At least not according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata</strike>

EDIT: As grawity points out in the comments, it appears to have support for so-called POSIX ACLs, despite what that wikipedia-page says.

The permission denied message is a bit odd, then. I suspect the VPS adds some restrictions regarding that. Have you tried adding the acl option in `/etc/fstab`, and then rebooted?

Each line of the `/etc/fstab` file has six fields separated by whitespace (excluding lines that start with #, which are ignored). On the line where the second field is `/`, add `,acl` to the end of field 4. E.g. if field 4 just says `defaults`, change it to `defaults,acl`.

After you've rebooted, run `mount`, and check if it has been mounted with the acl option.

Comment: According to [the article on ReiserFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS), the manual page of `mount(8)`, and [my tests](http://pastie.org/1496372), ReiserFS _does_ support ACLs.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I should've been more critical to trusting that wikipedia page that quickly.

Comment: I contacted my VPS provider and they said it's a limitation as you are unable to perform these sorts of things due to the security limitations:/